# search pattern pair using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am looking for a solution to find search pattern pair.

```
awk '/Schedule:/,/Retention Level:/' /tmp/data
  Schedule:              Full
    Type:                Full Backup
    Calendar sched: Enabled
     Included Dates-----------
        Tuesday, Week 1
        Tuesday, Week 2
        Tuesday, Week 3
        Tuesday, Week 4
        Tuesday, Week 5
     Excluded Dates----------
        No specific exclude dates entered
        No exclude days of week entered
    Synthetic:           0
    Checksum Change Detection: 0
    PFI Recovery:        0
    Maximum MPX:         4
    Retention Level:     2 (3 weeks)
  Schedule:              INC
    Type:                Differential Incremental Backup
    Calendar sched: Enabled
     Included Dates-----------
        Sunday, Week 1
        Monday, Week 1
        Wednesday, Week 1
        Thursday, Week 1
        Friday, Week 1
        Saturday, Week 1
        Sunday, Week 2
        Monday, Week 2
        Wednesday, Week 2
        Thursday, Week 2
        Friday, Week 2
        Saturday, Week 2
        Sunday, Week 3
        Monday, Week 3
        Wednesday, Week 3
        Thursday, Week 3
        Friday, Week 3
        Saturday, Week 3
        Sunday, Week 4
        Monday, Week 4
        Wednesday, Week 4
        Thursday, Week 4
        Friday, Week 4
        Saturday, Week 4
        Sunday, Week 5
        Monday, Week 5
        Wednesday, Week 5
        Thursday, Week 5
        Friday, Week 5
        Saturday, Week 5
     Excluded Dates----------
        No specific exclude dates entered
        No exclude days of week entered
    PFI Recovery:        0
    Maximum MPX:         4
    Retention Level:     2 (3 weeks)
```

Above is the input

Desired Output is

```
Full Backup;Differential Incremental Backup , 3 weeks;3 weeks
```

Which is Type and Retention Level pair. So Under each Type: there is a Retention Level. I need all the pairs in desired output.

Additional Input file where more than 2 pairs of Type and Retention is available:

```
`  Schedule:              Montlhy_Full
    Type:                Full Backup
    Calendar sched: Enabled
     Included Dates-----------
        Wednesday, Week 3
     Excluded Dates----------
        No specific exclude dates entered
        No exclude days of week entered
    Synthetic:           0
    Checksum Change Detection: 0
    PFI Recovery:        0
    Maximum MPX:         4
    Retention Level:     5 (3 months)
  Schedule:              Weekly_Full
    Type:                Full Backup
    Calendar sched: Enabled
     Included Dates-----------
        Wednesday, Week 1
        Wednesday, Week 2
        Wednesday, Week 4
        Wednesday, Week 5
     Excluded Dates----------
        No specific exclude dates entered
        No exclude days of week entered
    Synthetic:           0
    Checksum Change Detection: 0
    PFI Recovery:        0
    Maximum MPX:         4
    Retention Level:     3 (1 month)
  Schedule:              Daily_Inc
    Type:                Differential Incremental Backup
    Calendar sched: Enabled
     Included Dates-----------
        Sunday, Week 1
        Monday, Week 1
        Tuesday, Week 1
        Thursday, Week 1
        Friday, Week 1
        Saturday, Week 1
        Sunday, Week 2
        Monday, Week 2
        Tuesday, Week 2
        Thursday, Week 2
        Friday, Week 2
        Saturday, Week 2
        Sunday, Week 3
        Monday, Week 3
        Tuesday, Week 3
        Thursday, Week 3
        Friday, Week 3
        Saturday, Week 3
        Sunday, Week 4
        Monday, Week 4
        Tuesday, Week 4
        Thursday, Week 4
        Friday, Week 4
        Saturday, Week 4
        Sunday, Week 5
        Monday, Week 5
        Tuesday, Week 5
        Thursday, Week 5
        Friday, Week 5
        Saturday, Week 5
     Excluded Dates----------
        No specific exclude dates entered
        No exclude days of week entered
    PFI Recovery:        0
    Maximum MPX:         4
    Retention Level:     2 (3 weeks)
```

`

Comment: can you crosscheck your desired output, it may be `Full Backup;3 weeks,Differential Incremental Backup , 3 weeks;`

Comment: Actually I want Type in once cell with ; seperation Full Backup; Differential Incremental Backup then , will provide me next cell which is respective retention i.e 3 weeks; 3 weeks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script:

```
awk '
  $1 == "Schedule:" { $1 = ""; S = $0 }
  $1 == "Type:" { $1 = ""; T = $0 }
  $1 == "Retention" && $2 == "Level:" {
    sub(/^.*\(/,"")
    sub(/\).*/,"")
    print S ", " T ", " $0
  }' \
  $1
```

produces

```
 Full,  Full Backup, 3 weeks
 INC,  Differential Incremental Backup, 3 weeks
```

This one

```
awk '
  BEGIN { SEP = "" }
  # if line starts with 'Type:', remove that label,
  # add separator and remainder of line to T
  $1 == "Type:" { $1 = ""; T = T SEP $0 }
  # Retention level lines, add only what's between
  # brackets to L, set separator to ";"
  $1 == "Retention" && $2 == "Level:" {
    sub(/^.*\(/," ")
    sub(/\).*/,"")
    L = L SEP $0
    if (SEP == "") {
      SEP = ";"
    }
  }
  END {
      sub(/^ */,"",T)
      print T "," L
  }' \
  $1
```

produces

```
Full Backup; Full Backup; Differential Incremental Backup, 3 months; 1 month; 3 weeks
```

Comment: You hope or you fear?  I fear you're right.

Comment: Thanks @Gerard, However I was looking for Type to be clubbed together with semicolon and then after comma retention respective to type.

Actually I want Type in once cell with ; seperation Full Backup; Differential Incremental Backup then , will provide me next cell which is respective retention i.e 3 weeks; 3 weeks

Comment: I gave it another try.

Comment: Hi Gerard, Could you please explain the solution. And it gives space at the beginning of the output.

Comment: Hi Gerard, Please explain the solution, also 1 small issue, it only gives 2 pairs, what if there are 4 to 5 similar pairs it's not showing all Type and retention pairs.

Comment: Can you provide sample input file?  Put it on a share if not here.

Comment: It is exactly similar just instead of two pairs like Full Backup; Differential Incremental Backup, 3 weeks; 3 weeks. there could be more like Full Backup; Full Backup; Differential Incremental Backup, 3 months; 3 weeks; 3 weeks And so on, there could be max of 5 such pairs.

Comment: So it shouldn't be too difficult to provide a sample?

Comment: Hi Gerard, I added the input, the point is it is one of the inputs, there are multiple such inputs where there could be 2/3/4/5 pairs of type and retention. For e.g it could be Application Backup; Full Backup; Full Backup; Differential Incremental Backup, 1 week;3 week;3 week;1 month. So is it possible to get a generic code for any such pairs?

Comment: I've edited the second script.

Comment: One small query, in case you there are more such pairs will it capture it? Also could you please spare some time to explain the code for future understanding.

Comment: if you accept the answer, I will add comments.

Comment: Sure thing.......

Comment: There's plentyof documentation available, but I had to learn it from the makers of Unix, they wrote good books too.

Comment: Hi Gerard, hope you are doing good, I have got another request which i am trying to figure out, I need to include another Line item now, let me know if you can help, I am going to post another question with reference to this post.

Answer (score 1):

Try also

```
awk -F"[:)(]" '/Schedule:/,/Retention Level:/ {if (/Type/) printf "%s, ", $NF; if (/Retention/) print $(NF-1)}' /tmp/data
                Full Backup, 3 weeks
                Differential Incremental Backup, 3 weeks
```

**EDIT:** Or

```
 awk -F"[:)(]" '/Schedule:/,/Retention Level:/ {if (/Type/) TYP = TYP ";" $NF; if (/Retention/) RET = RET ";" $(NF-1)} END {gsub (/; */, ";", TYP); print substr (TYP, 2) "," substr (RET, 2)}' /tmp/data
Full Backup;Differential Incremental Backup,3 weeks;3 weeks
```